# CSES Python different TLEs in Cpython3/PyPy3

Tags: python, list, input

I'm trying out CSES Subarray Sum II - https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1661 and I'm sure of the logic but I'm getting different TLEs in CPython and PyPy3

Here's my code:

```
from sys import stdin, stdout
 
_, x = list(map(int,stdin.readline().split()))
arr = list(map(int,stdin.readline().split()))
 
d = {0: 1}
 
curr_sum = 0
ans = 0
 
for num in arr:
    curr_sum += num
    ans += d.get(curr_sum - x, 0)
    d[curr_sum] = d.get(curr_sum, 0) + 1
 
stdout.write(str(ans))
```

Here's my result in PyPy3:

[image: PyPy3 Result]

And here's my result in CPython3:

[image: CPython3 Result]

Description:

- PyPy3 - TestCase 25 fails with TLE, but 26 and 27 pass with less than 0.2 seconds
- CPython3 - TestCase 25 passes with 0.85 seconds, but 26 and 27 fail with TLE.

All 3 TestCases have an input size of `2*10^5`

I think the logic is correct, but I wanted to see if I've missed anything, or if there are any other optimizations I can try.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to put your code into a function. Local variable access is faster than global variable access, and you access `d`, `curr_sum`, `ans`, and `num` quite a lot.

Other than that your code seems to be well-optimized.

```
from sys import stdin
 
def solve(x, arr):
    d = {0: 1}
    curr_sum = ans = 0
    for num in arr:
       curr_sum += num
       ans += d.get(curr_sum - x, 0)
       d[curr_sum] = d.get(curr_sum, 0) + 1
    return ans

_, x = list(map(int,stdin.readline().split()))
arr = list(map(int,stdin.readline().split()))
print(solve(x, arr))
```

If you still get time-limit-exceeded for any of Python3 or PyPy3, you may want to contact the problem authors. Maybe they have set too strict timeouts by accident, or Python3 and PyPy3 are not supported for this problem set.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your suggestion and wrapped it in a function but it didn't work for me, I'll contact the authors if I don't find a fix over the next few days.